# Can we get a better quality question for grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem

Tags: support, asking-questions, new-users, question-quality

In doing some reviews, I came across a user who had this error issue, and was asking about a **grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem** issue.

I figured I would mark it as a duplicate, **being a common issue,** however when I looked at the protected question:

[Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

It is full of:

---

Blabbity blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah ntfs blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah xp blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

oh and then blah blbha blbha biityy fruit smack blah blah bald blah reboot thes oao ase blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah

Blah blah blah now I have an error and blah blah blah

$~ sudo blah /x11/confusing jargon

blah blahbbity blah

**Update**:

Blah blah blah and now my system is like this blah blah blah, and I tried this, blah blah blah

**Update** 2:

Blah blah blah, some stuff I tried blah blah blah

```
Technical jargon listed

confusing/stuff~# xv/sda/blah/blah 
$sudo de blah blah blah x#@?`
```

more blah blah

**Update** 3:

Blah blah blah, some stuff I tried blah blah blah

`Technical jargon listed`

more blah blah

**Update** 4:

Blah blah blah, some stuff I tried blah blah blah

`Technical jargon listed`

more blah blah

**Update** 5:  Blah blah blah, some stuff I tried blah blah blah

`Technical jargon listed`

more blah blah

```
This question is protected by the community
```

---

**I barely have the patience or stamina to read all this, and would rather send a hurting ubuntu newbie to a question such as:**

---

I booted my computer, and it says

```
Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem
```

What do I do?

---

Can we create this question make sure it isn't downvoted to oblivion?